# Check the continuity of $f$ and $g$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, multivariable-calculus, continuity

Let $$
f(x,y)=
\begin{cases}
\frac{1-\cos(x+y)}{x^2+y^2}, &(x,y)\neq 0\\
\frac{1}{2}, & (x,y)= 0
\end{cases}
$$
and
$$
g(x,y)=
\begin{cases}
\frac{1-\cos(x+y)}{\left({x+y}\right)^2}, & x+y\neq 0\\
\frac{1}{2}, & x+y=0
\end{cases}
$$

1. $f$ is continuous at $(0,0)$
2. $f$ is continuous everywhere except at $(0,0)$
3. $g$ is continuous at $(0,0)$
4. $g$ is continuous everywhere

**My attempt**
I tried the sequential criterion using the sequence I took the sequence $(x_n,y_n)=(1/n,-1/n)$. Then, $f(x_n,y_n)=\frac{0}{1/n^2}$ which converges to $0$. So, $f(x,y)$ is not continuous at $(x,y)=(0,0)$. So, (1) and (2) are right.

I tried counter example for the sequence contradict the continuity. I couldn't find. I tried to prove,
for given $\varepsilon>0$, $|f(x,y)-f(0,0)|=\left|\frac{1-\cos(x+y)}{x^2+y^2}-\frac{1}{2}\right| = \left|\frac{2-2\cos(x+y)-x^2-y^2}{2(x^2+y^2)}\right|$. How do I proceed further and find the desired neighbourhood?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nice choice of sequence for the first part.

For $g$, note that $g$ is clearly continuous on the plane with $x=-y$ deleted. This deleted line includes the origin also.

So you only need to consider the image of the set $\{x \approx -y\}$ under $g$, in other words, $x = -y + h$ with $0 < |h|\ll 1$. Plug in $x = -y + h$ into $g$ and then take limits :)